# WatchOS App: What is lifecycle of WKInterfaceController?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacecontroller

Anyone explain me correct way the WKInterfaceController lifecycle?

I would like to know how to use when creating an interface controller, WatchKit instantiates the class and calls its **-init, -awakeWithContext, -willActivate, -didAppear, -willDisappear, -didDeactivate** method.

How to track one by one method in WKInterfaceController?